# How to pass the scope of this correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble with the scope of `this` in the following:

```
var test = {

    $divs: $('div'),

    init: function() {
        this.$divs.each(function(){
            $(this).on('click', test.whatsmyid);
            $(window).on("resize", test.whatsmyid);
        });
    },

    whatsmyid: function() {
        console.log($(this).attr("id"));
    }

};

test.init();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4NZgd/1/

The click event handles the scope of `this` correctly but the window resize doesn't.  I understand the reason is that `this` isn't being passed to the window resize event but I don't want to pass the element to `whatsmyid` using a variable so how do I get around this?

Comment: what do you mean by `window.attr('id')`, what do you expect to log? ?

Comment: this is exactly my problem! I want the whatsmyid function to run for each div on window resize...

Comment: it does already, you just log the wrong thing

Comment: Sergio you know I meant that I want the div's id to be logged :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because `this` when called by `resize` is the window. Windows object doesnt have `id`'s. That's why it return `undefined`.

if you want to change the `this` inside the function, you can use `.bind` :

```
$(window).on("resize", test.whatsmyid.bind(this));
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/4NZgd/2/

Answer (score 1):

I know an answer has already been accepted for this however not every browser supports .bind meaning anything below IE 9.

so here's an alternative answer

http://jsfiddle.net/4NZgd/9/

```
var test = {

$divs: $('div'),

init: function() {
    this.$divs.each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $(this).on('click', test.whatsmyid);
        $(window).on("resize", function () {
            test.whatsmyid.call($this);
        });
    });
},

whatsmyid: function() {
    console.log($(this).attr("id"));
}
```

};

test.init();

Answer (score 0):

I like to pass eventData to the bind function. Basically, eventData is javascript PlainObject and you can pass information for the event. [jQuery bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)

```
var varModule = {
    $divs: $("div"),
    init: function() {
        var me = this;

        me.$divs.each(function() {
            $(this).bind("click", { me: $(this) }, me.findID);
            $(window).bind("resize", { me: me }, me.findID);
        });
    },
    findID: function(event) {
        var me = event.data.me;    //You will get PlainObject in event.data
        console.log(me.attr("id"));    //div object will give you id but window object wont give you id attribute
    }
};

(function() {
    varModule.init();
})();
```